# Entity Framework Core table configuration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I need help to configure table using `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, problem is that it creates table, but I can't choose maximum variable range.

I tried exact same code with modelbuilder and perfectly works, but in different classes no, and also warning message pops up:

> No store type was specified for the decimal property 'ProductPrice' on entity type 'Product'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values in 'OnModelCreating' using 'HasColumnType', specify precision and scale using 'HasPrecision', or configure a value converter using 'HasConversion'

This message appears for every decimal variable, but not a single column range is right.

Here is my code:

```
public class ProductConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Product");

        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.ProductName)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(30);

        builder.Property(e => e.ProductNumber)
               .IsRequired(false)
               .HasMaxLength(50);

        builder.Property(e => e.Color)
               .IsRequired(false)
               .HasMaxLength(15);

        builder.Property(e => e.ProductPrice)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)");

        builder.Property(e => e.ShippingPrice)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)")
               .HasDefaultValue(0);

        builder.Property(e => e.ShippingDimensions)
               .IsRequired(false)
               .HasMaxLength(40);

        builder.Property(e => e.ShippingWeight)
               .HasColumnType("decimal(6,1)")
               .IsRequired(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.Describtion)
               .IsRequired(false)
               .HasMaxLength(100);

        builder.Property(e => e.ModifiedDate)
               .HasColumnType("datetime")
               .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

        builder.Property(e => e.PhotoFileName)
               .HasMaxLength(100);

        builder.HasOne(e => e.ActivatedAccount)
               .WithMany(a => a.Products)
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasOne(e => e.Category)
               .WithMany(c => c.Products)
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
               .IsRequired(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the class and ef version used.

Comment: The only reason I see for this code not doing what is expected is if the code is actually **not called**. Make sure you have `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfig());` in your `OnModelCreating` override.

Comment: EF Version is 7.0.2 , 
I have no Idea from where should I call it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: you were right about not calling it, thanks a lot

Comment: Please add this as an answer or otherwise you may want to delete the question so people won't see it as an unanswered question any longer.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where is add as an answer button